# What is the state of Visual Studio 2012 RC integration with SourceSafe?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-studio-2012

I've installed Visual Studio 2012 RC and tried to do some work on one of my 'work' projects. It seems to work but after showing some upgrade screens and a Source Safe Login box Visual Studio 2012 RC crashes silently.

So my question is, what is the source safe support of Visual Studio 2012.

Should it just work or could it be not supported? Any pointers to blogs and official release would be really appreciated

Comment: Don't depend on it. [Time to upgrade to TFS](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/upgrade-visual-sourcesafe) and give a try to the [Express RC](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#tfs-express)

Comment: Wish I could, that would place the entire responsibility of creating a TFS environment to me. And what I've seen of it that would not an easy task to complete. (@KMoraz I'm installing the TFS Express version as we speak)

Comment: @CodingBarfield If creating a TFS environment is a problem, you may try out hosted TFS service. There are some providers providing the service. Some [search results](https://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&q=TFS+Hosting+Service+D&oq=TFS+Hosting+Service+D&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...801.21368.0.21621.54.32.19.2.2.1.319.6522.0j20j11j1.32.0...0.0.6aMMH6AEo-8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=2810c966fc342b24&biw=1366&bih=610) for your reference.

Comment: Its setting up the environment and getting a 'big' team with various skill level to switch from Source Safe to TFS without giving the management enough reason to do so.

Comment: you can try starting from tfs hosting. microsoft recommended several [tfs hosting providers](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server/hosting) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual SourceSafe is supported with Visual Studio 2012. Could you install the Visual Studio Feedback Tool (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8a5aac8-0418-4f88-9d34-bdbe2c4cfe72) to send us details on this issue?

1. Install VS 11 Feedback tool
2. Restart VS
3. Help menu | Report a bug
4. Log in using your Live ID
5. Type = "Crash"
6. Enter a descriptive title
7. In the Description field, enumerate the exact *minimal* steps to reproduce the issue
8. Press "Record" button
9. Go through the steps to reproduce the crash on VS
10. Press "Stop Recording" button after the crash
11. Press "Submit" button

This will send a Connect bug to us which we can then review internally and follow up on. You will be able to communicate with us and see the actions taken on your bug via http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/**[ConnectID]** where the **[ConnectID]** will be given to you after step 10.

Thanks for reporting this issue.

Comment: I'll do this as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also post here the ConnectID the Feedback tells you? That way I can look it up easily in our internal bug database.

Comment: I've submitted a report. ConnectID 748364 Thanks for you're help. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/details/748364 If you need any more information just ask.

Comment: Thanks! We'll take a look and communicate with you via the bug.

Comment: One of my colleagues seems to work with SourceSafe problem less but on a different project and not over the VPN.

Comment: I can't get the upload tool to work reliably. Can you check if they'll accept a download link for the file instead?