# Visual Source Safe and Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

Sorry for stupid question , but is there any chance to integrate vs2012 with Source Safe , if so , where can I download Visual source safe for Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: see if this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857457/what-is-the-state-of-visual-studio-2012-rc-integration-with-sourcesafe

Comment: Do you know where vs source safe can be downloaded ? Google doesn't gie me any good results. Or it comes only with Visual studio 2005 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146433/visual-sourcesafe-download but consider using something else than Sourcesafe, because in June 2012 Microsoft retired support and development for it.

Comment: Why dont you use Team Foundation Server? There is a free Express version for TFS 2012. Integrates perfectly and easily with VS2012

Comment: All sources are already in VSC , and I don't want to transfer everything to TFS.